# How to hide the code of a single cell in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Is it possible to hide a code in one particular cell in Jupiter Notebook? If so, how can I do it?

I tried to use Metadata in Cells settings. I also tried to use HTML `display` formatting, but it hides all cells.

I was reading about `nbconvert`, but this approach is not clear to me.

In my notebooks I have many cells with markdown and code. I should hide only the code of only one cell, while showing its output. How can I do it?

Comment: are you trying to hide the code because there is a password or key inside it? im not sure if its possible to hide code itself while executing it, but you can alternatively keep that code snippet in a local file, then read the file in and evaluate it

Comment: Noodling with this one for a bit, it would seem that Javascript would be your best bet here. If you can find a way to identify the right element with `class="inner_cell"` you can set its `display` CSS attribute to `none` and it will not be shown. Easy to do this manually, but you would need to trigger behaviour by detecting specific content. jQuery might be helpful.